# linq C# why the value change

Tags: c#, linq

Easily say, why those two `qqq` are different in the breakpoint?
`TodayInformation` and `YesterdayInformation` actually are type of `List<MyClass>`

It is very strange that as usually, `YesterdayInformation` couldn't be any changes through this part, but actually `YesterdayInformation` is updated as `TodayInformation` I never use any `pointer` or `reference`?

```
            var qqq = YesterdayInformation;
            var TodayInformation = YesterdayInformation;
            TodayInformation.Select(o =>
            {
                o.Signal = SignalpairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.signal).First();
                o.SigmaMove = SigmaMovepairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.SigmaMove).First();
                o.Date = Today;

                return o;
            }).ToList();
            qqq = YesterdayInformation;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here. Please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `TodayInformation` and `YesterdayInformation` are the same reference. You have a query of `TodayInormation`, but you modified each item in `.Select` method. Your query does something like:

```
var TodayInformation = YesterdayInformation;
foreach(var o in TodayInformation)
{
    //you are modifying each item of TodayInformation collection
    o.Signal = SignalpairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.signal).First();
    o.SigmaMove = SigmaMovepairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.SigmaMove).First();
    o.Date = Today;
}
```

I think you want this:

```
var TodayInformation = YesterdayInformation;
var result = TodayInformation.Select(o => new
    {
        Signal = SignalpairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.signal).First(),
        SigmaMove = SigmaMovepairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.SigmaMove).First(),
        Date = Today
    }).ToList();
```

This query loops over the collection `TodayInformation`, loads the data to an anonymous object without modifying the original item, and set the result list into a variable.

Comment: @ Danny Chen does that mean every `=` in C#  use `reference` don't like the `=` in C++?

Comment: It depends. `a = b` assigns the reference if they are reference types. For value types, `=` copies the value.

Comment: `TodayInformation` and `YesterdayInformation` actually are type of `List<MyClass>` so, they are reference type?

Comment: @user6703592 Yes, that is a reference type, and yes, both variabls point to the same instance. No copy is made.

Comment: @  Maarten even I use `List<Information> TodayInformation = new List<Information>();
                TodayInformation.AddRange(YesterdayInformation);` it doesn't work yet, why？

Comment: @user6703592 This is because items in the two lists are reference types. You created a new list using "new" keyword, the two lists are different reference since then. But the items in them are still same. You modification to items of `TodayInformation` applies to `YesterdayInformation`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are saying or asking, but the code as-in is basically a loop updating the items.

This would be a lot clearer, and equivalent to your code.

```
var TodayInformation = YesterdayInformation;
foreach (var oin TodayInformation) {
    o.Signal = SignalpairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.signal).First();
    o.SigmaMove = SigmaMovepairList.Where(p => p.pair == o.pair).Select(p => p.SigmaMove).First();
    o.Date = Today;
}
```